# getting error while calling an array inside a component from a class

Tags: reactjs

I have a written a simple ReactJS code to get an array of records from Store class using getRecords method and I am printing that array in View component inside a list component using map function. But I am getting an error that is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRecords' of undefined`. Please tell what is the issue in my code?

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import View from './View.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <View />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**View.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Store from './Store.js';

class View extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container" style={{marginTop:'25px'}}>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    <li style={{backgroundColor:'#696969', color:'#f5f5f5', textAlign:'center', padding:'5px', fontSize:'16px', borderRadius:'5px 5px 0px 0px'}}><b>Records</b></li>
                    {this.Store.getRecords.map((eachRecord,index) =>
                        <li key={index} className="list-group-item" style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
                            <b>{this.props.eachRecord.name}</b>
                            <button style={{float:'right'}}>Delete</button>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </ul>
                <input type="text"/>
                <button>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default View;
```

**Store.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Store {

    records: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'First Record',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Second Record',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Third Record',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Fourth Record',
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Fifth Record',
        }
    ];

    getRecords() {
        return this.records;
    }
};

export default Store;
```

Comment: You are not assigning `this.Store` inside the component in `View.jsx`, so it is undefined.

Comment: Your store should just be accessible as `Store`, as opposed to `this.Store`.